# Выходит ошибка в терминале когда ввожу pip

Tags: python, django

"pip" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Помогите пожайлуста!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у вас Windows 10, то выполните следующее:
Открываем в панели управления пункт система далее нажимаем на Дополнительные параметры системы далее переменные среды, а после измените параметр Path и добавьте туда следующее:

1. ваш путь к Python
2. ваш путь к Python\Scripts\

(Это мой пример)

1. C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\
2. C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\